# how to generate active record models from database

Tags: ruby, database, activerecord

I am looking for a tool or a method which can convert my huge old database to active records model definitions ... like reverse engineering ...

Comment: This isn't "reverse engineering". Reverse engineering implies some kind of encryption/obfuscation, while you have the complete plain-text "source" to your database schema.

Comment: ~meagar that's not the meaning of reverse engineering.

Comment: This rare_map gem does what you expect to be done:
https://github.com/wnameless/rare_map

Answer (score 6):

This is less a reverse engineering problem and more a "does your legacy database adhere to the active record conventions" problem. Most do not and from my experience, it's almost easier to do some migration work on the data end to get it in a state such that it does adhere to those conventions. Rails is a very opinionated piece of software, the less you argue with it, the happier you'll be.

My two cents...

Comment: @meagar is right though, if the table representing your model does adhere accordingly, simply extend ActiveRecord::Base

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't know a tool either. But creating an active record model is really simple as meager showed it. Additionally you may have to describe the table name and the primary key:

```
class Artikelgruppe < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "tblArtGrp"
  set_primary_key "ArtGrpID"
end
```

As my Rails application uses only a small subset of our legacy database I prefer to create views specific to the needs of my application in the database. I have really problems to describe a join over eg 7 models in Rails but it is really easy to create a view for joining 7 tables in the database.

Why do the Rails people still think they are the centrum of the universe? I have a dozen applications written in different languages and the common ground is the database. Imagine I would have to change the database to make Rails happy ...

Answer (score 1):

[RMRE](https://github.com/bosko/rmre) seems to be the best of the two listed here. You can either run it in your rails root after making a special rare_map.yml that is just the DB config for the database you want it to scan. That goes either in ./config if you are under rails, or in the root directory of you app if not.

One nice thing: For non-rails apps it will generate a [module]_base.rb that creates a separate ActiveRecord::Base and it will stuff the classes into a module of your choosing and make a separate ActiveRecord::Base for each.

The models RMRE generates have all the relations (belong_to, has_many, etc.) filled out for you automagically. It will for non-rails apps or if you specify it in your config stuff the models into a Module for you.

The [rare_map](https://github.com/wnameless/rare_map) gem also mentioned above only created empty models for me, which does not buy you a whole lot.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord will do that for you. You don't actually have to specify columns in your models. Assuming a complete `users` table, simply put the following in `app/models/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

What ever additional validation you want to perform can be added afterwards.

That said, you probably don't want to do this. Rails is notoriously difficult for those attempting to port old projects, due to Rail's "convention over configuration" motto. It will be an uphill battle if you attempt to bend Rails to your existing database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RMRE](https://github.com/bosko/rmre) gem. Here's an [introducing blog post](http://pragdevnotes.com/2010/09/30/rmre-rails-models-reverse-engineering-gem) written by RMRE author.

Comment: link only answers are discouraged