# Ruby on Rails - Is there a way to generate a scaffold script from database tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I already have the database tables and I need to create the rails script

```
  rails generate scaffold ...
```

Is there a way or a tool ?

Thanks.

EDIT: usually I do
rails generate scaffold myObj1 columna:id, columnB:string
rails generate scaffold myOdb2 columna:id, columnB:string
and it create everything including dbg script.

I want to create the script from the db now. because I already have the db tables.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I think you mean reverse engineering the database. See [this other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138502/how-to-generate-active-record-models-from-database) question

Answer (score 0):

Just run the scaffold, and delete the migration file it creates, since you already have the table in the database.

Comment: my question is - if I have 30 database objects, can I reverse it to scaffold commands - so that I wouldnt have to write it from scratch.

Comment: Yeah, but you're only going to have to do it once.  If you have a schema.db file, start with that, otherwise do some show columns queries on the database and redirect it into a text file.  Bring it up in a text editor and do text replacement until you've massaged the original format into a shell script to call rails generate scaffold myObj1 columna:id, columnB:string.

Comment: Looking back at this, I really didn't answer the question because you wanted to reverse the schema into scaffold commands.  But I want to leave this answer, because there are no other answers and it is better than nothing.